# What's the best way to duplicate the standard out of a process to both standard out and a file?

Tags: ruby, unix

When I do `$stdout.puts "foo"`, I want it to go to both stdout and to a file.

I came up with:

```
def log_init
  $stdout.sync = true
  old_out = $stdout.dup
  old_out.sync = true
  r, w = IO.pipe
  $stdout.reopen(w)
  fork do
    f = File.open('/tmp/test', 'a') do |f|
      f.sync = true
      while (sel = IO.select([r], [], [], 1000))
        readfds, *rest = sel
        data = readfds.first.readpartial(1024)
        old_out.write(data)
        f.write(data)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Can you do this without requiring a second process?

Answer (score 2):

Just do it from the shell:

```
   your-program | tee file
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this post/thread from the Ruby mailing list may help you along: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/102759#226506

In particular this piece of code:

```
["$stdout", "$stderr"].each do |std|
  io           = eval(std)
  old_write    = io.method(:write)

  class << io
    self
  end.module_eval do
    define_method(:write) do |text|
      unless text =~ /^[\r\n]+$/       # Because puts calls twice.
        File.open("logfile.log", "a") do |f|
          f.puts [std[1..-1].upcase, caller[2], text].join(" ")
        end
      end

      old_write.call(text)
    end
  end
end

$stdout.puts "text on stdout"
$stderr.puts "text on stderr"
```